# Return statement giving undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, return

I am having a function:`fetchAll` which is in the `fetch.js` file.

```
import axios from "../axios";

export default function fetchAll() {
  axios.get("/api/videos/all").then((response) => {
    return response.data;
  });
}
```

Then in `Home.js`:

```
import fetchAll from "../functions/fetch";


 useEffect(() => {
  var videos = fetchAll();
  console.log(videos);
 },[])
```

But the function returns `undefined` instead of the data. 
Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

You are not returning anything from `fetchAll` function.

```
export default function fetchAll() {
  axios.get("/api/videos/all").then((response) => {
    return response.data;
  });
  // <-- no return, void return
}
```

## Solution

Return the Promise from `axios`

```
export default function fetchAll() {
  return axios.get("/api/videos/all").then((response) => {
    return response.data;
  });
}
```

You will, of course, need to wait for the Promise to resolve in the `useEffect` callback.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getFetchAll = async () => {
    try {
      const videos = await fetchAll();
      console.log(videos);
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  getFetchAll();
},[]);
```